# redux-persist, save only first 10 items using Transform

Tags: redux, redux-persist

I'm trying to save only 2 items when persisting through `redux-persist` .

I'm perplexed why the following code won't work..
(it seems to save more than 2 items)

```
const myTransform = createTransform(
  (inboundState, key) => {

    let { openforum_threads } = inboundState

    if (!openforum_threads) {
      return inboundState
    }

    let { allIds } = openforum_threads

    let STORE_NUM = 2
    let storeIds = allIds.slice(0, STORE_NUM)
    console.log('saving', storeIds)
    let { byId } = openforum_threads

    let storeById = {}
    storeIds.map((id) => {
      storeById[id] = byId[id]
    })

    openforum_threads = {
      ...openforum_threads,
      allIds: storeIds,
      byId: storeById
    }


    return { ...inboundState, openforum_threads}
  },
  (outboundState, key) => {
    // convert mySet to an Array.
    return outboundState
  }
)
```